# How send POST request with JSON, NOT as string?

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

My app sends a POST request that way:

```
URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConnection.connect();

// Write
OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
writer.write(jsonString);
writer.close();
output.close();
urlConnection.disconnect();
```

But the API can't decode it because it is a string. So:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

just returns an empty array.

How do I write just the JSON in the body of the request?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to parse your `jsonString`. So your code should be:

```
writer.write(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Comment: The way I created the writer just let me insert a `String` there